# How to iterate looking for a time redundancy in event records?

Tags: oracle, plsql, iteration

*The use case:*

I am creating an web page where a person can subscribe in some scheduled public events.

The database tables are `Persons -> Subscriptions -> Events -> Days -> Activities`

*The restriction:*

This person can subscribe on every event available, as long as those events don't have one or more activities in common in one or more days.

*The solution:*

So when the user tries to subscribe into an event, the database should iterate other active events where he/she is already subscribed, looking for events with same day, using times from `StartMoment` and `EndMoment` fields of this `Days` table.

*How to:*

I am new to Oracle. I am used to Firebird and MySQL and I never need to use *iterators* before. I just did that king of check inside my programming code, but now I want this logic to be in the database to be independent of platform.

Can anyone tell what is the smartest way to do that, in a way that the code don't get too messy and too slow?

*The Data (simplified):*

```
  Table Persons: Id, name(varchar), identify(varchar), phone(varchar);
  Table Subscriptions: Id, personId, eventId, reg_date(date);
  Table Events: Id, description(string), hours, contacts(string);
  Table Days: Id, eventId, day(date), begin(time), end(time), allday(bool);
  Table Activities: Id, dayId, eventId, begin(time), end(time), duration(0 for allday, or minutes), description(varchar);
```

Comment: why do you need `iterators` ? it looks that it can be done via simple SQLs same way as on MySQL and Firebird...  `select count(*) from where exists (some logic)` ... if you provide script to create the tables and insert test data it will be more easy to help you with the code

Comment: Because every Event can have N days not sequential, so I need to look in every day of every subscribed event to test with each day of the Event I want to subscribe.

Comment: can you provide scripts to create the tables and your test data?

Comment: I Shaw translate before post. They are in Portuguese.

Comment: This article https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/1942.the-cursor-for-loop from ToadWorld describes what I need: a Cursor for Loop, where the cursor is the query of all days from my `Days` table, and the Loop is used to compare it with a query of days from every other Events the person is subscribed.

Comment: ok, see answer below. you need `Implicit Cursor FOR LOOP Statement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to iterate through each record in tables the easiest way would be use `for rc in (select * from mytable) loop  end loop;` syntax. this is implicit cursor for a statement see more information here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CHDBJBJE
and your logic will be:

```
begin
  for rcPersons in (select * from Persons) loop
    for rcSubscriptions in (select * from Subscriptions where personId= rcPersons.Id) loop
       for rcEvents in (select * from Events where id = rcSubscriptions.eventId) loop
          null; --<do some logic here>      
       end loop;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

`p.s if you provide scripts to create test tables and data it would be easy to find most effective solution. I think it could be done via one SQL, but need more info to be sure`